# What is the best approach to add buttons on top of the screen in Swift

Tags: xcode, storyboard, swift2, ios9

I am trying to make an app that reads calendar events, and makes a list of meetings in Swift 2. I need to make it look like this:

[image: app]

The top part is always visible. The list will be scrollable, and the list will load different data when user clicks on a different day. Also the days in the top bar need to adjust when user scrolls to the end of the day, and continues scrolling (days must shift one step further).
I try to do this with Navigation Controller with the navigation bar.

Is this the right way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A nice approach would be to use just a separate "container" view, which holds the buttons, and have the scroll view on the same level as this "container". This way the view will on top will not scroll.

Regarding the changing of the top buttons based on the scroll - you can use the `UIScrollViewDelegate` to get the exact position. Since I do not know the exact scenario, I cannot advise what is the best way to determine the day based on the scroll position.

Comment: thanks, I am going to try this today. the container view and table view must be both reacting to each other's changes. Can I achieve this with delegate pattern?

Comment: For the changes from the tableView - you already have a delegate for the ScrollView (the table is actually a subclass of the ScrollView). For the changes from the top view with the days - you better use a ready component like collection (as @user3820674 suggested). And since the view controller will be responsible for both of them and the delegation of both of them will be received by the viewController, you can react on their changes.

Answer (score 0):

> But is this the right approach

If you mean "Can the days be in the navigation bar", then no. That is not the right approach.

Comment: If you want the days to stay while other stuff slides in and out, then you will have to code that yourself. For example you might use a custom parent view controller. The built-in UINavigationController, on its own, is not going to allow you to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right all you need is implement a collection view which scrolls horizontaly. Table view will reload every time you tap collection view cell (didSelectItemAtIndexPath method).
Cheers.

Comment: Thanks, reload data when click - this part is pretty clear, but which view to use - is more unclear. I will try this now.

Comment: "but which view to use - is more unclear" - I can not understand you.

Comment: i mean your answer is what I wanted (probably) - because I did not know what is collection view, and now I am going to investigate

Comment: OK. And I offer you to investigate Core Data for save your a day list.

Answer (score 0):

I just set the scrollview.frame to accommodate for button height on the top of the view controller. Make sure if your using storyboards you don't have the buttons on top of the scrollview.

```
    let width = self.view.frame.size.width
    button1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, width / 4, 40)
    button2.frame = CGRectMake(width / 4, 0, width / 4, 40)
    button3.frame = CGRectMake((width / 4) * 2, 0, width / 4, 40)
    button4.frame = CGRectMake((width / 4) * 3, 0, width / 4, 40)
    button5.frame = CGRectMake(0, 41, width / 4, 40)
    button6.frame = CGRectMake(width / 4, 41, width / 4, 40)
    button7.frame = CGRectMake((width / 4) * 2, 41, width / 4, 40)
    button8.frame = CGRectMake((width / 4) * 3, 41, width / 4, 40)

    // scrollview frame size
    scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 80, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height)
    scrollView.contentSize.height = self.view.frame.height
    scrollViewHeight = scrollView.frame.size.height
```